# Why does the KJV say "people perish" in Pr. 29:18?

Tags: septuagint, kjv, masoretic-text

Can anyone tell me why the KJV translates the Hebrew words *yipara am* as “people perish” in Pr. 29:18? (The Hebrew word *am* means people and *yipara* means unrestrained.) Other translations render *yipara am* as “the people run wild,” and “the people cast off restraint.” YLT says, “Without a Vision is a people made naked.” Brenton says, “There shall be no interpreter to a sinful nation: but he that observes the law is blessed.” The Lexham English Septuagint says, “A seer will never come to a lawless people, but those who keep the law are most blessed.” The JPS Tanakh: The Holy Scriptures according to the Masoretic Text (1917) translates *yipara am* as “the people cast off restraint.” What am I missing here?

Comment: Welcome to BH. Your question up-voted (+1) as I think it is a good one.

Answer (score 4):

The KJV largely used the Bishop's Bible translation which also translates it the same.

> When the worde of God is not preached, the people perishe: but well is hym that kepeth the lawe

The Bishop's bible got that from the Latin translation, not the Hebrew directly.

> cum prophetia defecerit dissipabitur populus qui custodit legem beatus est

We see the word dissipabitur which is the word for destroyed or perished.

For the most part the KJV used The Bishop's Bible text as primary source and consulted many other languages as well as original language materials for their translation. Most of the KJV is really an updated English version from Bishop's and Geneva not doing a lot of original source translating. [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King_James_Version#Sources) [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bishops%27_Bible)